# confused on isotropic BRDF

Tags: brdf, pbr

I am reading a paper and there is a part I don't understand:
[image]

I am wondering why the isotropic BRDF only depends on the view direction and roughness? Why is the light direction not related?

Comment: I think that it does depend on it, it just does not depend on $\phi$. Where's the reference from?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzvWIdpUpRx_d09ndGVjNVJzZjA/view, from page 4.

Comment: The GGX distribution term they are referring to doesn't take $l$ as argument. However you can see that they do have other terms that take $l$ into account.